# how can i validate the following the following input in python (Hex spaced values)

Tags: python, hex

I have a string which is ascii encoded,spaced hex format

```
a="%27+%2B+%27%27+%2B+%2701 01 01 02 04 12
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'
"
```

i need a validation which can check whether it has valid characters or not

the solution i came with is

```
def Check():
    while False:
        for char in Hex:
            if char not in Valid:
                print ('That is an invalid hex value.')
        print('That is a valid hex value.')
        return Check

Hex=int(input('Enter a hex number: '), 16)
Valid='1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''10''A''B''C''D''E''F'
```

Comment: What valid characters. please provide an **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: if you check the input which i provided, its an invalid because it has special characters in it.  i want  validation which check for valid character only.

Comment: Ya mean, `%` and `+`

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
Hex=input('Enter a hex number: ')
Valid='12345678910ABCDEF'
d={True:'That is a valid hex value.', False:'That is an invalid hex value.'}
print(d[all(i in Valid for i in str(Hex))])
```

Example outputs:

```
Enter a hex number: 0123456789
That is a valid hex value.
```

---

```
Enter a hex number: $%*@345572
That is an invalid hex value.
```

Comment: i am able to achieve that, but if provide input as '11 34 66', it gives out ValueError        
    Hex=int(input('Enter a hex number: '), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '11 01'

Comment: @rakesh Wait, copy my whole code and run it, that's the way it's gonna work.